# My background image with repeat-x property gets chopped off

Tags: css, background

I'm having an issue with a background image with repeat-x property :S
On Windows OS, it seems working fine but not on Mac.
When I open the web, I see bunch of white space chopped off on the right side
and it corrects itself when resizing the size of the window :O
I think my method to set its width has a problem but cannot figure out exactly why.

http://www.sangminkim.com/sample/index.html

This is the url for the page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything strange, what browser and version?

Comment: Safari has a problem. Forgot to mention that. Sorry.

Comment: If you open it in a small window and scroll to the right, you will be a big white space :( that's what im trying to get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue: Background image doesn't display when starting from a small view and scrolling to the right.

This issue cannot be solved. If you inspect the HTML and BODY elements, the background stops where the elements stop. The HTML and BODY elements cannot be larger than the view port. This is a common issue and cannot be corrected (it even happens on the footer of StackOverflow).

Comment: Uh oh.... :( Sad to hear that... I just used min-width property as a second plan.. Thank you Matthew!